# File exchange over DNS Tunneling

Tags: penetration-test, firewalls, dns

I want to demonstrate an attacking scenario in which DNS tunneling is used to get information out of a protected network. There is the compromised host behind the firewall, at which the client is installed and it needs to send a file over the DNS tunneled connection to a server controlled by the attacker.

I have set up the DNS tunneling using [DNSCat2](https://github.com/iagox86/dnscat2). I can connect the client to the server and interact, I even have shell.

What I want is to transfer a file from the victim host to the server using the DNS tunnel only. <s>I cannot seem to find this functionality</s>*, is there any way to accomplish it?

* EDIT: RTFM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I skipped this part on documentation, the tool offers both download and upload functionality.
After you get server running and connect a client, you can start a session on the server with:

```
session -i 1
```

and then

```
download/upload <path/of/the/file>
```

and this way you can exchange files over DNS tunneling.

Answer (score 3):

There are literally tons of ways to do this, but the simplest is to transfer them over text.

- For example, you can base64 encode the file and echo it out to the remote host (or vice versa) then decode the base64 on the other side.
- There's also [this](https://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2014/12/10/awkward-binary-file-transfers-with-cut-and-paste/comment-page-1/) technique demonstrated by SANS.
- Be creative!

Answer (score 0):

The tunnel only provides you with a remote shell, nothing more. To receive files you'll need to use an other protocol, FTP, RSYNC or even SSH.

You can also setup the DNS tunnel, bind a local SSH or SOCKS daemon on a high TCP port, then use a remote SSH (initiated from the server) towards the DNS client, this essentially turns the compromised host into a server within the internal network. You can leverage from this to exploit the internal network any further. Of course this is beyond your question.

Comment: I have already been able to transfer a file from victim to remote server with scp, using my shell session, but my restrictions are the behind the firewall everything is blocked for the victim, accept from the dns requests. So, the question is, is there a way to use the DNS quering mechanism to transfer files over DNS tunneling (in my case and in general)?

Comment: @antonis_man Yes that is what I was referring to. You establish these protocols OVER the tunnel.

Comment: @YorickdeWid I would be curious to see how you set up a TCP exchange within an UDP protocol, moreover when there's an internal DNS server in the path.

Comment: @Tensibai This happens all the time with tunnels. TCP packets are incapsulated in large (512+) UDP packets. VPN servers do no different

Comment: @YorickdeWid Well this leaves me a strange 'I don't get how this could work' with an output only UDP flow (with a two way flow I could get it). I've to dig the subject on how you could send a TCP SYN/ACK within a DNS query). I you have some link to start from I'll be happy

Comment: @Tensibai There is no *output only*. The entire exploit works because firewalls *cannot* block incomming UDP traffic on 53. Checkout the iodine source, it has a much smaller codebase than DNSCat2 and builds on OpenVPN network drivers.

Comment: @YorickdeWid I assume you mean 'from 53', what I don't exactly get is how you can establish a TCP session when it's always the same host originating requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45156/discussion-between-yorick-de-wid-and-tensibai).

Comment: When you are on remote windows machine, you can extract username and password (legally with no need for exploits) and then use it to connect to the web proxy server.

Comment: Or you can even use email client on the system if you are impatient.

Comment: @Aria The OP talks about a firewall, and without anymore details it is reasonable to assume outgoing mail is prohibited.

Comment: So maybe intercept keystrokes and try to get onto jumpbox ;-)